# Using Flask: bootstrap works but custom stylesheet doesnt't

Tags: css, flask

I have checked the other topics, they seem similar but won't solve my problem:
I am writing a web application using flask and bootstrap works fine but my custom stylesheet gets completely ignored and I can't figure out why.

```
  <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>C$50 Final_Project: {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>    
  </head>
```

Comment: This means that your CSS file is not correctly loaded. Try to specify relative path instead of absolute path as you did> /static/styles.css -> static/style.css.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. When I follow my original link it ends up exactly where it is supposed to be. If I change it to your suggestion, I get the error, that it doesn't exist. Thank you though.

Comment: Check your browser console, what are the errors and warnings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Browser cache needed to be cleared...

I am not sure why this question was downvoted so much, but I probably should have added, that the path for static.css is not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Compiled CSS and JS instead?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/

and maybe try to use "url_for" for the file path
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') }}">`

Comment: Also, try diffrent orders  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Rules-to-override-Style-Sheet-Rule-in-CSS